# Is this a JBOSS web service? Tomcat? How to create a server.xml file?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, web-services, server.xml

I am working on a webservice that a previous employee built and I am just trying to figure out what documentation I need to be looking at.  I think that the webservice is using JBOSS and therefore using Apache Tomcat. In the project there are several webservices so it is somewhat tricky to tell which is using what.  (What are shared files etc).  **Question Number One**: How can I verify that it is using JBOSS?

My job is to make the webservice use bi-directional key exchange.  I have done this before but this webservce does not have a `server.xml` file.  I am confused about where this could be or if the ws is just using the default values.  **Question Number Two**: Can I create a new server.xml?  If I do create one where should I link it in?  I have:

- folder: name.ear containing application.xml
- folder: name.war containing folder: WEB-INF containing: web.xml
- name.wsdl

For anyone else working on the same thing this is a great documentation of web.xml:
http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml

Comment: JBoss AS is a Java EE based application server which uses Tomcat as webcontainer (servletcontainer). Thus, Tomcat is just part of JBoss AS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss is using Tomcat for web application, that means that there are both of them :)
You can find `server.xml` somewhere at `server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/conf/`

Check http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r5/html/ch01.html for more information about JBoss basic configuration

Comment: Indeed, vendor's own docs ought to be first place to look for answers on this kind of questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Where is it usually deployed? And what is the artifact ear,sar or war?

If it's a war it could be running on tomcat (with dependecies resolved).

I would recommend that you start with a fresh installation of jboss to learn about the dependencies of your inherited project, add the jars one by one.

The `server.xml` file should be controled by the admins and not depend on an application.