# Can we deploy Jboss WS on tomcat server

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jbossws

Can we deploy Jboss WS on tomcat server

I tried doing it on tomcat 7 , after including the jars for Jboss Ws , i got the error org/bboss/kernel/Kernel class not found exception , then i added a jar for jboss-kernel-2.2.0.GA.jar

Please share your experience on the same.

Thanks
Abhi

Comment: So it did work after you added the kernel?

Comment: Simple answer: yes, because JBoss uses Tomcat behind the scenes. There is a similar question for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2284410/1065197

Comment: No its not working, it says java.lang.NullPointerException , org.jboss.wsf.common.KernelAwareSPIFactory.getKernelProvidedSPI( KernelAwareSPIFactory.java:38)

Comment: Which  Jboss ?  Jboss 7 uses a fork of Tomcat.

Comment: I have deployed the Webservices on tomcat 7 , which were earlier deployed on jboss 4.2.3, is JbossWS compatible with tomcat , what are the steps, if any one has experinced it.

Comment: With no solution , moved to JAXWS web service , worked on both jboss and tomcat